# bootstrap 3.3 modal remote content gives 404

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, http-status-code-404

I'm using Bootstrap with a couple of components (removing them individually didn't fix the problem - but for the sake of completeness, here's a list).

I'd like to load remote content (test.html) into a Modal. It all works fine on a standalone html page, but when I insert the exact same code into my project's layout, nodemon gives me a "GET test.html 404". **The Modal still opens**, but the remote page isn't loaded (apparently it can't find it, and I don't understand why) and the "yada yada" appears in the modal-body instead.

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/pinboot.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>

<script>
      $("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
        var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
        $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
      });
</script>

<a href="test.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">Launch Modal</a>

<!-- Default bootstrap modal example -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">yada yada</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm secretly hoping this is a common problem with a simple solution and I'm just not feeding Google the right questions/keywords :( 
So in that case I thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake ... it was the routing. Everything not defined in app.js was directed to a script that couldn't handle it, sort of.
app.get(  '/', routes.index );

Renaming test.html in test.ejs and adding this to app.js...

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   res.render('test');
});
```

...and changing the button to link to /test

```
  <a href="/test" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default">Launch Modal</a>
```

...made it work. Hooray!

I'm gonna leave that here for the next n00b ;)